# Why can't I import firebase in my vite javascript code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vite

When I try to run my code I get the following error message:

[image: error message]

The code works completely fine without the firebase stuff inside.

Here is the relevant `main.js` (assume API Key etc. has info in it) and `firebase_app.js` (it is completely unaltered from the way it was).

```
//This is my main.js
import "./style.css";
import Phaser from "phaser";
import RexUIPlugin from 'phaser3-rex-plugins/templates/ui/ui-plugin.js';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
});
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);


//This is my firebase_app.js
import {
  DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME,
  FirebaseError,
  SDK_VERSION,
  _addComponent,
  _addOrOverwriteComponent,
  _apps,
  _clearComponents,
  _components,
  _getProvider,
  _registerComponent,
  _removeServiceInstance,
  deleteApp,
  getApp,
  getApps,
  initializeApp,
  onLog,
  registerVersion,
  setLogLevel
} from "./chunk-QLRY5HZI.js";
import "./chunk-LQ2VYIYD.js";

// node_modules/firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm.js
var name = "firebase";
var version = "10.8.0";
registerVersion(name, version, "app");
export {
  FirebaseError,
  SDK_VERSION,
  DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME as _DEFAULT_ENTRY_NAME,
  _addComponent,
  _addOrOverwriteComponent,
  _apps,
  _clearComponents,
  _components,
  _getProvider,
  _registerComponent,
  _removeServiceInstance,
  deleteApp,
  getApp,
  getApps,
  initializeApp,
  onLog,
  registerVersion,
  setLogLevel
```

I attempted to remove everything except the imports. It still gives the same error.

I removed all of the firebase related code. It worked fine.

Comment: The imports in `main.js` are incorrect if you are using Modular SDK. I'm not sure why you have `firebase_app.js` (or is it part of the build?). If the linked duplicate doesn't work out, can you please post more details and error (as text)?